# AngularJS : why button hide after click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to open menu menu opening on button click .I am able to show menu option .But I am facing one issue my button is hide when menu option is display.menu should display below the button.I need to show  button as well as menu when user click on button.I need menu should display below button

here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPaOKJ

```
var app = angular.module("ionicApp", ['ionic']);
app.directive('custommenu', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            $(element).menu();
        }
    }
})
app.controller('cnt', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isMenuVisible = false;
    $scope.showMenu = function () {
        $scope.isMenuVisible = true;

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

the button does not hide.

Try add `margin-top: 30px;` to `.menu`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbdQgN